# UITableViewCell with black background

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know this may be obvious, but i didn't set the background to any color in IB. My code for the `UITableView` is this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_listeDesChapitres objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

What I get is this:

[image: Table view cells have black background]

The cell background is black by default, until I click it to see its text. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the background of the label, and the background of the cell:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

instead of:

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```